# alternative to scipy's matrix exponential

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using one of the new MacBooks with the M1 chip. I cannot use SciPy natively unless I go through Rosetta, but for other reasons I cannot do that now.

The ONLY thing I need from SciPy is `scipy.linalg.expm`. Is there an alternative library where there is an implementation of expm that is equally (or almost equally) fast?

Comment: The actual code is in `scipy.sparse.linalg.expm`, and uses a (relatively) complex Pade approximation.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are still working with `numpy`?  I'd have to check the `expm` code, but I don't think it uses extra `scipy` compiled code.  It does use  an array inverse, but I think the rest of the approximation is expressed in Python (the coefficients and so on).  It also takes different approximations depending on the shape of the array.

Comment: Another consideration, what size of exponent?

Comment: Yes I'm still using numpy, but I don't think it has an implementation of `expm`? Anyway, I'm trying now to copy all of the relevant code from scipy, perhaps that will suffice.

Comment: I guess just copying the relevant classes/functions in a single file worked, but I wish I could just use SciPy directly : /